# Laptop screen does not switch off after shutdown

Tags: gnome, shutdown, 16.10

### system

- **Dell Vostro 3550**
- **Ubuntu 16.10**
- **Gnome Desktop**

The problem has recently arised when I either use the GUI button or terminal command `sudo shutdown -h now` where the machine freezes with the Gnome symbol.

I tried pressing the key  <kbd>ESC</kbd>  while the machine was shutting down and it did not show any sort of error or warning messages.

[image]

And the machine freezes as usual.

However I believe that system does shutdown properly because on reboot there are no  `orphaned inodes` or `recovering journal on /dev/sdx` messages, which commonly occur when the laptop is suddenly switched off.

Does this have to do anything with the OS itself or is it pertaining to hardware? Are there some files that can tweaked to debug this issue?

Comment: Make sure the OS is fully updated before anything else.

Comment: I have. However do you suggest I do a `dist-upgrade` ?

Comment: Yes  (or `sudo apt full-upgrade` which is the preferred command since 16.04).

Comment: It is fully upgraded.